# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error due to Button

Tags: swift, xcode

I am still learning swift and Xcode so please explain as much as possible in layman's terms so i can understand and try to fix this issue, i'm getting a sigbrt error, but not sure why. Ive created tons of buttons and linked it to the viewcontroller.swift which i have done, but for the life of me, i can not see why i am getting this error. Any help would be very much appreciated.

First here is the debug error:

```
2018-11-26 20:30:42.713790+0000 Numbers[2058:130834] -[Numerology.twoViewController generateYourNumbersButtonPress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fac2973d5a0
2018-11-26 20:30:42.724547+0000 Numbers[2058:130834] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Numbers.twoViewController generateYourNumbersButtonPress:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fac2973d5a0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e6a1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106448735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e88f44 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000010a823b4a -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e6eed6 ___forwarding___ + 1446
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e70da8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000010a7f6ecb -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000010a2320bd -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000010a2323da -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000010a23131e -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 583
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a8320a4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2729
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a8337a0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4080
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a811394 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a8e65a9 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3054
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a8e91cb __handleEventQueueInternal + 5948
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107dcf721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107dcef93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107dc963f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107dc8e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ff861dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000010a7f581d UIApplicationMain + 140
    21  Numbers                          0x0000000105b17ed7 main + 71
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109303575 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Below is My Code:

```
import UIKit

class twoViewController: UIViewController {
    let ballArray = ["brownBall1","brownBall2","bbrownBall3","brownBall4","brownball5","lightBlue6","lightBlue7","lightBlue8","lightBlue9","lightBlue10","yellowBall11","yellowBall12","yellowBall13","yellowBall14","yellowball15","silverBall16","silverBall17","silverBall18","silverBall19","silverBall20","redBall21","redBall22","redBall23","redBall24","redBall25","purpleBall26","purpleBall27","purpleBall28","purpleBall29","purpleBall30","greenBall31","greenball32","greenball33","greenball34","greenBall35","goldBall36","goldBall37","goldBall38","goldBall39","goldBall40","blueBall41","blueBall42","blueBall43","blueBall44","blueball45","blackBall46","blackBall47","blackBall48","blackBall49","blackBall50"]

    let luckyStarArray = ["goldOne", "goldTwo", "goldThree", "goldFour", "goldFive", "goldSix", "goldSeven", "goldEight", "goldBballNine"]

    @IBOutlet weak var starView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var starView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var starView3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var starView4: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var starView5: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var luckyStar1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var luckyStar2: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func generateYourNumbersButtonPress(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let shuffledBallArray = ballArray.shuffled()

            starView1.image = UIImage(named: shuffledBallArray[0])
            starView2.image = UIImage(named: shuffledBallArray[1])
            starView3.image = UIImage(named: shuffledBallArray[2])
            starView4.image = UIImage(named: shuffledBallArray[3])
            starView5.image = UIImage(named: shuffledBallArray[4])

            let shuffledLuckyBallArray = luckyStarArray.shuffled()

            luckyStar1.image = UIImage(named: shuffledLuckyBallArray[0])
            luckyStar2.image = UIImage(named: shuffledLuckyBallArray[1])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code so you can see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't put `generateYourNumbersButtonPress` inside of `viewDidLoad`.

Second, mark `generateYourNumbersButtonPress` as an `@IBAction`.

Third, reconnect the action to the button after fixing the above two issues so you connect the proper action method to the button's event.

Comment: I done the First and Second, but did not need to do the third, as the connection was still there and the yellow triangle had now disappeared. Thank you for your help.